# integer declaration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsinteger

I am struggling with bug in my program. and finally i got the point. here integer shows value 1 at the time of declaration. I clean and build again. but it shows 1 value?

please any one explain me why this happen?

[image]

Comment: Say: NSLog(@"display value: %i", numberOfRecords); right after the declaration, this will be the real value, it might be some trash from the memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare a local variable without specifying a value, you need to assign it first before reading from it becomes valid. The `1` that you see in your integer variable could be any garbage value, it is unspecified. Reading this value is undefined behavior.

```
int numberOfRecords = 0;
```

This is different from instance variables, which are initialized by default.

Comment: Wanted to add this for further clarification - If its local variable, there could be any garbage value. If its class instance variable, int will be initialized to 0 for you.

Comment: @0x8badf00d Thanks for an excellent comment, I modified the answer to mention this.